# FFmpeg read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters

Tags: ffmpeg

Getting error

> ```
> "read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters"
> ```

My code:

```
ffmpeg -i "/root/nisar/a.mp4" \
-map 0:0 -map 0:0 -map 0:0 -map 0:0 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
-c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 3000k -filter:v:0 "scale=1920:1080" -preset fast -profile:v high -level 4.0 -tune film \
-c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:1 2000k -filter:v:1 "scale=1280:720" -preset fast -profile:v main, -level 3.1 -tune film \
-c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:2 1200k -filter:v:2 "scale=960:540" -preset fast -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -tune film \
-c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:3 800k -filter:v:3 "scale=640:360" -preset fast -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -tune film \
-c:v:3 libx264 -b:v:4 500k -filter:v:4 "scale=480:270" -preset fast -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -tune film \
-c:a:0 aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" \
-async 1 -vsync 1 \
"/root/nisar/output.mp4"
```

Error:

```
Only '-vf scale=1920:1080' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-vf scale=1280:720' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-vf scale=960:540' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-vf scale=640:360' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-vf scale=480:270' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters
Only '-af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters
```

Please find the attached screenshot

[image] and advise me.

Answer (score 7):

It's a false positive in this case. You can ignore it. The check is supposed to catch duplicate filter invocations for the *same* output stream, e.g. `-filter:v:0 scale=hd1080 -filter:v:0 hue=s=0` where only the hue would get applied. The correct way is `-filter:v:0 "scale=hd1080,hue=s=0"`. But the check is buggy.

Fixed in [version 4.3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7712).